# Bullseye with Visual

Tags: code-coverage, bullseye

i have issue with bullseye coverage.

I need to run bullseye coverage from command line for continious integration.

I use commands:

```
covselect.exe --file test.cov --add .\ 

cov01.exe --on 

MSBuild /maxcpucount:8 /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x64" MVPF.sln 


MSBuild /maxcpucount:8 /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x64" MVPFTest.sln 

cov01.exe --off

covxml -f test.cov -o bullseyecoverage-result.xml
```

but i have empty test.cov and report.xml files into working directory.

Could you explain what i should to do step by step for coverage measuring?

Answer (score 0):

Your commands look good so far.
But you don't execute your tests. The tests need to be executed in order to measure the coverage. With the build you are only instrumenting the code.
So the steps should be :

1. cov01.exe --on
2. MSBuild /maxcpucount:8 /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x64" MVPF.sln
3. MSBuild /maxcpucount:8 /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
   /p:Platform="x64" MVPFTest.sln
4. MVPFTest.exe
5. cov01.exe --off

I like to add

```
cov01.exe -s
```

because then I see in the Jenkins Console print out the status.

Answer (score -2):

yeah I realize its super old question but it is high in search engine. You need to run a program so the coverage files can be created. The general steps are:
1) Build with coverage flags (or with BE on like you did)
2) Run something that uses what you have built. The program itself or some tests
3) Collects results